# jquery not working in css

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having trouble getting my code to work and I'm not sure why.
Here is the link to the jsfiddle.

[Js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6keau71u/)

```js
$(document).ready(funciton() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("h1").css("color", "red");
  });
});
```

```html
<h1>
Testing123
</h1>
<button>
  Make the h1 red
</button>
```

Comment: It works, you just need to include the jQuery library. https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/m76npdc2/1/

Comment: You misspelled function.

Answer (score 2):

you have to include the jquery library link in order to use the jquery nomenclature.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also you have a typo in the first line

```
$(document).ready(funciton() {...
```

should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {...
```